# Swift - Cascade on delete in SharkORM

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, dbaccess

I'm using SharkORM in Swift to create an SQLite database, the issue is that I have two tables with one-to-many relationship using foreign key, I need to know if there is a way to implement cascading on delete on these two tables,

When I delete a record from the primary table, all the records with its foreign key in the details table should be deleted automatically, I don't want to implement this manually.

So is there a way to implement cascading on delete using SharkORM? I already went through documentations and couldn't find anything,

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So if you take the example of `Person -> Department`, where person contains a `.department` property. Then you cascade these deletes via the `entityWillDelete` method.

An example is 'something' like this.

```
class Department: SRKObject {

   ...

   override func entityWillDelete() -> BOOL {
       Person.query()
             .whereWithFormat("department = %@", parameters:[self])
             .fetch()
             .removeAll()
       return true
   }

}
```

With relationships, always look to the inverse.

The documentation for `entityWillDelete` mentions this here.

```
/**
 * Before SharkORM attempts an operation it will ask the 
 * persitable class if it would like to continue with this operation.
 *
 * @return BOOL if YES is returned then SharkORM WILL complete the operation 
 * and it is guaranteed to complete.  All pre-requisite checks have been made 
 * and the statement compiled before getting to this point.  
 * It is safe to use this method to cascade operations to other classes. 
 * In the case of delete, you might wish to delete related records, or 
 * indeed remove this object from related tables.
 */
- (BOOL)entityWillDelete;
```

This is all done within a transaction, including all the cascades and event trigger changes.  Which can then all be rolled back in the case of a failure/error/abort.